# JavaScript DOM changes and can longer interact with page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I’m making a chrome extension and it's working. In this extension I parse data from a dynamic page, and then insert it into a new div which I then hide and unhide with the CSS visibility rule (via JavaScript DOM)

Problem is, after I hide the new div when done looking at it, the underlying page is no longer interactive. Can't click anything. Can't type into the interactive field to make updates etc.

Any ideas, anyone ever have an issue similar to this that they had to solve?!

Comment: It is hard to be sure without code, but I have some ideas. It could be that javascript is being stuck in a infinite loop, which never lets the main thread of the browser do anything else. Or it could be that some part of the element you created is somehow blocking the normal elements. The way to find out would be by 1 setting a breakpoint in js to see if it completes and 2 by looking at the dom in devtools and seeing if anything could be blocking.

Comment: I'll look into that! Sounds reasonable. Still learning so I while I knew about setting breakpoints and checking the dom in devtools, I hadn't really thought to do that since the code I was injecting felt super self explanatory and I figured its something silly.
Thanks, i'll look into the dom and set some breakpoints and see if I can track down the cause of the issue!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You probably modify innerHTML of body, which is a mistake.

Comment: Looking into that! Responded to @peterduffy in another thread about diagnosing; I started chunking the code because I was struggling with breakpoint usage with my extension without using snippets (which I havent learned exactly yet)

Chunked in the first set of code that begins setting my extension up and it immediately does it! I think you are right, in that it is happening because im using innerHTML.

I tried it right before reading your comment actually and then I see your comment and lo and behold, an innerHTML.
https://gist.github.com/GottaBeTheJuice/86e559c8b0fe3cb9c6780620bf0b8a03

Answer (score 0):

The visibility attribute makes the element invisible, but it's still there and it takes up space. That is probably why it is blocking you from interacting with the content behind it.

Try instead using `display: none;`.

Comment: I thought the same thing but then I tested it out and it seems like visibility: hidden makes the element unable to block clicks.

Comment: @peterduffy Ah, you might be right. Not much we can do without his source code except to guess. I will remove this answer if the issue is revealed

Comment: Thanks, I changed it and it seems to have made the behavior better in other aspects! BUT, the bug is still present and it actually made me discover that it was due to the button I was adding inline in a pre-made div on the page. THAT is the issue, still have no clue how to fix it, but now at least I have a tail to pull on to try and figure it out. 

Your response has helped me in dialing in on the actual problem when I thought it was being caused by the div overlay I created, its the button!! .

I'll edit my post when I find the solution for the community.

Thanks @Berthur

Comment: @GottaBeTheJuice Good to be of use anyway :)

Comment: @Berthur Not to derail the original topic necessarily, but WHY would adding a button with a simple 

`<button id='foo'>buttonName</button> `

into the innerHTML of something even cause the page to lose all interactivity?! Cant click links or anything, but mousing over shows they are still there too just cant click them or anything etc.

Comment: @GottaBeTheJuice I don't know why. But it is really hard to tell without code. If you don't want to post all of the code because of privacy or something you can try to remove unimportant bits that don't effect the behavior of the bug.

Comment: I don’t mind posting it, but I feel like it’s just a lot to go through and I really don’t want to make it feel like I’m expecting someone to go through it all. Not that it’s an insane amount. But it’s about 300lines. 

I may later(or tomorrow) chunk it out and only add the button in like a few lines of code and see if it’s that or something else, if that makes sense. 

Seems like it’d be the professional way to go about it anyway, but idk, I’m still learning to hopefully become employable one day hah.

Comment: For example, I had the idea to remove the button and only keep the base functionality. And manually invoke the functions that create  the div and the data that it throws in there after passing.  And then see if it still removes page interactivity. 

Before I added buttons when I was debugging and designing the functionality and making it work, I don’t recall the bug being present, but I might have just not come across it as the focus was the foundation of the functionality itself!

Comment: @GottaBeTheJuice No I also can't tell straight away what might be causing it. Try to reduce your code into the simplest example that still shows the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example